# ¿Como implementar una consulta para obtener la fecha mas reciente?

Tags: mysql

tengo la siguiente consulta de `MYSQL` en la cual necesito implementarle la fecha más recientes de `pedidos_reportes`.

```
SELECT pedidos.*,
reporte.*,
usuarios.*,
pedidos_reportes.*
FROM pedidos  
LEFT JOIN pedidos_reportes 
ON pedidos.ID = pedidos_reportes.id_pedido
LEFT JOIN reporte 
ON pedidos_reportes.id_reporte = reporte.id
LEFT JOIN usuarios 
ON pedidos_reportes.id_usuario = usuarios.id
WHERE fecha_modificacion BETWEEN '2021-06-02 16:05:11' AND now()
```

Ya realice algo que me trae las fechas mas recientes, pero al quererlo implementar a mi consulta, me duplica la información.

Este es el código como lo intento hacer:

```
SELECT pedidos.*,
reporte.*,
usuarios.*,
pedidos_reportes.*
FROM pedidos  
LEFT JOIN pedidos_reportes 
ON pedidos.ID = pedidos_reportes.id_pedido
LEFT JOIN reporte 
ON pedidos_reportes.id_reporte = reporte.id
LEFT JOIN usuarios 
ON pedidos_reportes.id_usuario = usuarios.id
INNER JOIN (
SELECT id_pedido, 
MAX(fecha_modificacion) 
FROM pedidos_reportes 
GROUP BY id_pedido
) AS FechaMasActual
WHERE fecha_modificacion BETWEEN '2021-06-02 16:05:11' AND now()
```

[image: Este es el problema que me da al agregar el codigo]

Comment: ¿De qué manera muestra la duplicación de información?

Comment: No noté que si tenias la fecha mas reciente, pero que intento de implementación estás haciendo ??

Comment: @JeanGotopo Edite mi publicación, al final de ella agrego el codigo y la captura del error que me da

Comment: @Excorpion quiero solo agregar a mi consulta la fecha más reciente en el que editan un registro

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con algo como esto:

```
Select * from pedidos
WHERE fecha_modificacion  = (
    SELECT MAX(fecha_modificacion)
    FROM pedidos
)
```

De esta manera, puedes lograr lo que esperas: obtener la fecha más reciente.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución c: Vendría genial que explicaras lo que hace tu código tanto para el OP como para personas que vean tu respuesta en el futuro.